android studio created composable function for me but the argument types are not what I expected
I wrote in this part:
LemonTextAndImage(modifier, R.drawable.lemon_tree, R.string.LemonTree, R.string.step1)
and asked android studio to create me the composable function LemonTextAndImage, which it did, and it works. But for the three resources that I am passing to the function I expected the argument input to be drawable something, string something, but instead the resulting function call are INTS???
I am on Iguana, 2023.2.1 Patch 2.
when (currentStep) {
        1 -> {
            LemonTextAndImage(modifier, R.drawable.lemon_tree, R.string.LemonTree, R.string.step1)
        }
        2 -> {
            LemonTextAndImage(modifier, R.drawable.lemon_squeeze, R.string.Lemon, R.string.step2)
        }
    }


}

@Composable
fun LemonTextAndImage(modifier: Modifier, lemonTree: Int, lemonTree1: Int, step1: Int) ...


Resource identifiers are Int values. R.drawable.lemon_tree is an Int. R.string.LemonTree is an Int. That is not new to Compose -- resource identifiers have been integer values since Android 1.0 back in 2008.
